# Problem embedding a page on facebook

Tags: facebook, links

When I put the link to this page:

http://www.likeforisrael.info/

In facebook, I get the embed code to show a link to this page:

http://likeforisrael.info/NVnlO/

And idea why this happens?!

Comment: As-written, this is a **Facebook** (i.e. **Facebook API**) question, not a **WordPress development** question.

Comment: This is a problem which doesn't happen on any other website I know of.  I think this has to do with something wordpress is doing (although maybe I am wrong).  I wouldn't expect facebook people to know.  But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It still goes to the same page, so I assume its being added by facebook for a reason.. maybe for tracking or something.

Not sure if you have seen this, but a very good tutorial on embedding your site.

http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/embed-your-site-facebook

Comment: It goes to the same page because I am using a redirect plugin to fix it.  Thanks for the link though...